# Invalidate session with JSF2.0 Mojarra and JQuery

Tags: jsf-2

I'd like to invalidate session during window close in JSF2.0. So I've written below code to do that:

```
 var preventUnloadPrompt;
 var messageBeforeUnload = "my message here - Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
 $('a').live('click', function() {
    preventUnloadPrompt = true;
 });
 $('form').live('submit', function() {
    preventUnloadPrompt = true;
 });
 $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) {
    var rval;
    if (preventUnloadPrompt) {
        return;
    } else {
        // return messageBeforeUnload;
        doInvalidate();
    }
    return rval;
 });

function doInvalidate()
{
     $.ajax({
         url: "http://localhost:8080/MyPrj/SessionTimeout",
         type: 'GET'
     });
 }
```

And my servlet is as below:

```
 public class SessionTimeout extends HttpServlet {
    .....
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.err.println("IN SESSION TIMEOUT GET!!!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
   }
  .....
}
```

After launching my first JSF2.0 page (by this time FacesContext must have got initialized), I tried to close the window. The I can see my `SessionTimeout` servlet is getting called but `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();` is throwing`NullPointerException`. Why is it happening? Can't I see `FacesContext` during this AJAX call in my servlet? If above is not possible, can one suggest any other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FacesContext` is created by the `FacesServlet` and thus only available when the request is served by the `FacesServlet`. In other words, it's only available in JSF artifacts like managed beans, phase listeners, etc, but definitely not in a "plain vanilla" servlet which is invoked independently from JSF.

Just use the standard servlet API methods like as JSF is using "under the covers" (you know, JSF is a Servlet based MVC framework, heck the `FacesServlet` **is a** servlet!). To invalidate the session, just do [exactly the same](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#invalidateSession%28%29) as `ExternalContext#invalidateSession()` is doing.

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```